How OS code gets executed by microprocessor when microprocessor have limited set if instructions / opcodes
I've been trying to understand and did lot of online research but still have doubt:
If processor understands only opcodes (which are limited) then why is it possible to execute operating system code? For example, multitasking, scheduling, for them, there is some module / code in the operating system. If those "codes" aren't "made" by opcodes which a processor understand, then who understands the code (non opcode / "non-standard" code), that is, which is not within the "opcode list" of the processor.

These are called "syscalls", usually it's done through setting certain registers then raising a certain interrupt (which the OS sets up the interrupt vector to beforehand). Other answers (though its from the other side, user-space programs to OS interactions) go over this a lot better

Operating system only uses opcodes that the processor understands. All OS code is made from legal CPU opcodes.
Modern OSes do require some specific operations to be built into the CPU. For example, to run Linux, the CPU must have at least 2 privilege modes (and opcodes to switch them) and support virtual memory (and opcodes to configure it). If the CPU does not have those opcodes - a modern OS cannot run on such CPU. That's why there is no Linux on Zilog Z80.
Modern CPUs have some opcodes that only OS can use. Those are usually the opcodes that allow user programs to "break away" from OS rule. When the processor encounters one such opcode - it checks if the current code belongs to OS (how it is done - depends on the CPU). If it does not - the CPU will not perform the action, but will "snitch" to the OS instead. Note: those OS-only opcodes are still built into the CPU! It's just the CPU has additional conditions to check before it runs them.
Multitasking and scheduling is mostly done with normal opcodes - with only few OS-only opcodes sprinkled in. For example, multitasking on a single core looks like this:

The current program is interrupted to run OS code. This uses CPU's interrupt mechanism and a timer device.
Current state of the program is saved into memory. This is done completely with normal opcodes - you just save all registers that program have access to.
The next program to run is selected. Done with normal opcodes - you just read a list of processes and decide the next according to some rule or point system.
Virtual memory map is switched. Uses OS-only opcodes.
The state of the next program is restored from memory. Normal opcodes.
Jump back to program. OS-only opcode to tell the CPU to switch off OS privilege mode.


Thanks so much for the answer. Do you have any reference / pointers where you got this information for me to look further. These days the OS's are very sophisticated, does it mean they are able to do all this with limited set of Opcodes?

@CuriousMind Yes, it is all done with a limited set of instructions. In fact, 99% of all complex software is just arithmetic, conditional jumps and data copying.
Unfortunately, I cannot give you references. I didn't learn it through formal education. I guess, some university-level Operating systems textbook should have all this explained, but I don't know which book is good.
